# Replace # and \s from a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace <kbd>#</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> from a string if it has these two characters.

This is for markdown previewer.

```
var t = document.getElementById("textbox");

var h1 = (t.value === "/#\s/") ? t.value.replace(/^[#\s]/, "") : t.value;
console.log(h1);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `t.value === "/#\s/"` is true when t.value is *literally* and exactly `/#s/` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
let h1 = textbox.value.replace(/#| /g, '');
console.log(h1);
```

```html
<input id="textbox" value="H a v e Nice#Day###">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to categorically strip *all* pounds signs and spaces, then you should be using:

```js
//var t = document.getElementById("textbox");
var t = "Hello#World Goodbye";
t = t.replace(/[# ]/g, "");
console.log(t);
```

Note the character for space, is just space, not `\s`, which means all whitespace (including things like newlines and tabs).